# pandas dataframe: delete empty label name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe converted from tab seperated text file. But the first label is an extra unnecessary label.

```
   a   b   c
0  1   2   NaN
1  2   3   NaN
```

The label `a` is an extra one. The dataframe should be:

```
   b   c
0  1   2
1  2   3
```

How to remove `a`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can omit first header row by `skiprows` parameter and then add parameter `names` for new columns - is necessary same `length` of `names` and length of another rows of data:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=1, names=['b','c'])
print (df)
   b  c
0  1  2
1  2  3
```

Or more dynamic is get only first row by `nrows=0` for columns and then pass to parameter `names` with remove first value by indexing:

```
names = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=0).columns
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=1, names=names[1:])
```

Another idea is default columns - `RangeIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=1, header=None)
print (df)
   0  1
0  1  2
1  2  3
```

Comment: You are star as always. Dynamic one is great as I have too many `names` and I need to keep the other `names`